# Conemu, avoid fast-config dialog

Tags: conemu

I need to launch conemu from different locations in filesystem with same settings (also moving the config xml). The location of that config is (oddly) stored in the config itself, so if location changed, fastconfig dialog pops up at startup.

I see two options to avoid fasconfig dialog: messing with xml in the config, updating file each time, or storing configuration in the default storage, which is applied on -resetdefault key. That default config seems to be hardcoded...

Any other solutions?

Comment: Your question yes unclear. What do you want to launch?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "use portable version".

I'am not quite sure, why ConEmuPortable.exe cares about the app's path, anyway it checks Data/settings/ConEmuSettins.ini for this. 
With the task I have, I found it safe to launch App/ConEmu/ConEmu.exe directly. Wherever you put the portable pack, it sucsessfuly finds the right config file, with no alerts, storing configuration in ".Vanilla" section of ConEmu.xml

The only tiny thing is, just in case, don't launch the exe with Data/settings/ConEmu.xml deleted. You wil have very strange mess in the xml file, even with parts addressing nonexistent files, which won't go away even if you later replace it with a clean one. Use ConEmu.xml from conemuportable archive, if you need a fresh stock config file. I don't understand how this works.